# PHP, jquery ajax call not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I usually work with .NET but I have a php page that calls an ajax post through another php script with parameters, then calling  a stored procedured. But it does not work when trying to write to the mysql database. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, Thanks for any help.

jquery call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ValidateTest').hide(); 
            $('#cf_submit').click(function () { 
                if ($('#cf_message').val() == '' || $('# cf_name').val() == '') {
                    $('#ValidateTest').html('Please complete.').css({ 'color': 'red' }).show(); 
                    return;

                }

                var parameters = {
                    'name': $('#cf_name').val(),
                    'message': $('#cf_message').val()
                }; //Use JSON to pass parameters into ajax calls  


                //Make ajax call to post to database
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'SendTest.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: parameters,
                    success: function () {

                        $('#ValidateTest').html('Thank-you!').css({ 'color': 'green' }).show();

                    }
                });
            }); //End button click

        }); //end jquery call
```

php script

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'passw');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("", $con);
mysql_query("CALL sp_CreateTestimony("$_POST['message']", "$_POST['name']")");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: IT doesnt post to the database. I am not sure whats wrong. Also I checked firebug console and it doesnt even look like the ajax call is being called, even though the success function runs.

Comment: What [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) are you getting from mysql? Also, I'm assuming the missing quote before `host` is just a typo, but you should fix it.

Comment: I am not sure how to read any errors that I am getting, but what I have above, there is no error returning.

Comment: Step one is to add an `error` function to your ajax call so that you can see the problem.  Something like:  `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);}`

Comment: Added the error, still nothing, It runs the success function still

Comment: Don't stringify the params. 1. not all browsers have a JSON object with stringify and 2. the jQuery already url encodes the object you are passing.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was running the success function.  That means that the Ajax call didn't return an error.  It might be interesting to see what it did return -- change the success callback to be `success: function(data){alert(data)}` and see what you're getting.  Or use Firebug to see the full request and response for the Ajax call.

Comment: @user516883 I linked you to the function to return the mysql_error text. Here it is again: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Maybe its the way I am calling the ajax call because it is not even calling SendTest.php at all.

Comment: You might also check your use of quotes in the PHP. In the declaration of con you are missing a ' in front of host, in the mysql_query call you have issues with the double quotes and they need to be escaped.

Comment: add a data arg to the sucess functiona and see what it says. You are hitting some file that is returning properly or you would hit the error function. success: function(inData){console.log(inData);}

Comment: the missing quote was just a typo before i posted here, but can you give an example of the second part of your comment. Also if it was atleast getting to he SendTest.php part wouldnt it make a entry in firebug, I am not seeing anything

Comment: Something may be wrong with the URL because it even if I take that out it still does the exact same thing

Comment: Without the HTML it's hard to tell, but you should double-check and make sure the click event is attaching to the correct element. If the $.ajax call is never being made, then the click event probably isn't triggering at all. Are you sure you have your button/link/whatever with an ID of 'cf_submit'?

Comment: just for debugging return something from your php page to make sure that the ajax call was made to that page for ex: **echo json_encode(array('testmsg'=>'Success'));** add this statement at the end of the your php page and @ the success function just alert that **data.testmsg** like **success:function(data){ alert(data.testmsg)}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the ajax request using json. so firts you have to decode the json

```
 $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Then you can access message and name using $data array.